# Unable to start embedded container due to NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, maven, docker, spring-boot, dockerfile

My SpringBoot application work well with Eclipse IDE but when I run my application on Docker Container its image builds well but when I run the image it will get exceptions ClassDefnotfound and Unable to start embedded container.

```
 How can I fix it?`

In Dockerfile
FROM java:8
EXPOSE 8080
ADD /target/docker.ras.jar docker.ras.jar
RUN sh -c 'touch /docker.ras.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","docker.ras.jar"]

    In pom.xml i also use maven plugin
```

> ```
>     <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
>   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
>
>   <groupId>example.docker.ras</groupId>
>   <artifactId>docker.ras</artifactId>
>   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
>   <packaging>jar</packaging>
>       <parent>
>       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
>       <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
>       </parent>
>   <name>docker.ras</name>
>   <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
>   <properties>
>   
>   <java.version>1.8</java.version>
>   <start-class>docker.ras.App</start-class>
>   <docker.image.prefix>springio</docker.image.prefix>
>     <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
>   </properties>
>
>   <dependencies>
>   
>   <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>             <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>             <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
>
>         </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>     <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
>     <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
>           </dependency>
>
>   
>         <dependency>
>             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
>         </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
>         <scope>compile</scope>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
>     <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
>     <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
> </dependency>
>
>  <dependency>
>       <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
>       <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
>       
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
>     <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
>     <version>2.0</version>
>     <scope>compile</scope>
>  </dependency>
>
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>junit</groupId>
>       <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
>       <version>3.8.1</version>
>       <scope>test</scope>
>     </dependency>
>   </dependencies>
>   <build>
>   
>   <plugins>
>           <plugin>
>           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>           <executions>
>                     <execution>
>                         <goals>
>                             <goal>repackage</goal>
>                         </goals>
>                     </execution>
>                 </executions>
>       </plugin>
>       
>       <plugin>
>             <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
>             <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>             <version>0.4.11</version>
>             <configuration>
>                 <imageName>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</imageName>
>                 <dockerDirectory>src/main/docker</dockerDirectory>
>                 <resources>
>                     <resource>
>                         <targetPath>/</targetPath>
>                         <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
>                         <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
>                     </resource>
>                 </resources>
>             </configuration>
>         </plugin>
>   </plugins>
>   
>   <finalName>docker.ras</finalName>
>   </build>
>   </project>
> ```

[My Error Stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FifxB.png)

Comment: How do you build the application image (package) for Docker? Please amend your question with this information.

Comment: I did with the following commands on docker tool.                                 1.mvn install
2. docker build -f Dockerfile -t docker.ras .
3.docker images
4.docker run -p 8080:8080 docker.ras

Comment: Show us full text of exception, please.

Comment: As you are using Maven, please post your `pom.xml`. You should use the spring-boot-maven-plugin, as described here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

Comment: In pom.xml i also use maven plugin

Comment: Please add your pom.xml to the question. It is most probably where the problem is.

Comment: OK, great. And now the error message you receive (a stack trace, most probably).

Comment: For starters stop mixing spring versions... (spring boot 1.3.0 and 1.4.3 are mixed never mix versions of a framework).

Comment: Why are you using `javax.servlet:jsp-api` in version 2.0? That's damn old. Try e.g. using `javax.servlet.jsp:javax.servlet.jsp-api:2.3.1`. Note that groupId and artifactId have changed.

Comment: I changed version but still have the same error

Answer (score 0):

Check the Java Version in Docker Container.
hope you are running the app after artifact.
if so make sure it is adding all the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

This is either that you have included server specific APIs in your deployment or that you have your servlet API versions wrong.  I suspect the former.

If you're using maven check your servlet api has a scope of provided in the pom.

Also look at

http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html